# Controlling Combustion Chamber Pressure

Tags: rockets, thermodynamics, combustion

When designing a rocket engine, what degrees of freedom do you have to get the combustion chamber to a desired pressure?  I assume you have mass flow rate, type and mixture ratio of fuel and oxidizer, and geometry, but what aspects of the geometry matter?

With a given geometry, is there a way to calculate the minimum pressure to cause choked flow at the nozzle?

Comment: The existence of choked flow is solely a function of the pressure *ratio* for a given gas.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow#Minimum_pressure_ratio_required_for_choked_flow_to_occur

Comment: The pressure is less of a problem than the temperature.

Comment: And -from my observations - two "schools" - ALL aspects of the geometry matter - the whole path of flow, including the combustion phase is modeled and the chamber is shaped to that; general data like overall pressure go to PR publicity papers, while the actual plans have a precise layout of localized conditions and every centimeter of the chamber built to match and guide the local conditions it is facing - and NO geometry aspects matter; it's just a rough bottle shape where chaotic processes mix the gasses and they escape through the only opening to a (reasonably complex) nozzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combustion chamber is typically designed to ensure the combustion reaction goes to completion. This is often thought of in terms of characteristic length (L*). Where L* is equal to chamber volume / throat area. In practice, the smallest L* that will allow complete combustion can be found experimentally by measuring chamber temperature and characteristic velocity for different chamber lengths.